# How to remove fields with empty values in objects nested in an array - mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation

Need help with removing fields with empty values in array. So far, code is removing both values if one of the field is having empty value.
Example docment:

```
 {
  "_id": ObjectId("62ed3cfbeadf50344d622dd0"),
  "Status": 1,
  "AnswerList": [
    {
      "Question1": "some question1",
      "Question2": "some question2",
      "Answer": "",
      "Comment": "Some comment"
    },
    {
      "Question1": "some question1",
      "Question2": "some question2",
      "Answer": "some answer",
      "Comment": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

My query so far:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Survey: 1,
      Status: 1,
      AnswerList: {
        $map: {
          input: "$AnswerList",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $in: [
                  "",
                  [
                    "$this.Comment",
                    "$this.Answer"
                  ]
                ]
              },
              then: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: {
                      $map: {
                        input: {
                          $objectToArray: "$$this"
                        },
                        as: "element",
                        in: {
                          $cond: [
                            {
                              $in: [
                                "$$element.k",
                                [
                                  "Comment",
                                  "Answer"
                                ]
                              ]
                            },
                            null,
                            "$$element"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    as: "filter",
                    cond: "$$filter"
                  }
                }
              },
              else: "$$this"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is using `$map` and `$filter` with `$arrayToObject` and `$objectToArray`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Survey: 1,
      Status: 1,
      AnswerList: {
        $map: {
          input: "$AnswerList",
          as: "item",
          in: {$arrayToObject: {
              $filter: {
                input: {$objectToArray: "$$item"},
                as: "pair",
                cond: {$ne: ["$$pair.v", ""]}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OPnycjftteZ)